# magento product getName() not working after upgraded from 1.3x to 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento

After I upgraded a magento store from 1.3x to 1.7.0.2 by [this tutorial](http://turnkeye.com/blog/magento-upgrade-guide/), I met lots of problems, I got most of them solved but I cannot fix this weird one.

In backend, the product list works well, but if I go to the edit page of any product, the name/description and many field was empty (but categories / inventory works), it means all the product attributes cannot be load here.

Then I tried:

```
$product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load(some_id);
var_dump($product->getData());
```

I also cannot find any attribute value in there, if I write $product->getName() directly, I got NULL.

Does anyone can help with this ? At least point me a direction to solve this problem. I tried to look into the codes, but it's really hard to find how magento's load() function actually works.

Comment: Can you provide this information?1. please check eav_attribute table in database 2.Search the table with "attribute_code" as visibility check is there any entry for that

Comment: I've compared eav_attribute with a working 1.7 store, they're just the same(not empty attribute_code), or is there anything special I need to pay attention to ?

Comment: check source_model column for any particular row say "visibility" is there any entry catalog/product_visibility for that column, i faced this type of issue once and found that entry for that was not present.I was upgrading 1.4 to 1.7

Comment: I found one record for the attribute "visibility", but I think this is not a problem? the source_model is "catalog/product_visibility" for that attribute. (I found same record in a running 1.7 store)

Comment: check for other attribute if there then might be other issue sorry .

Comment: Ok! I will see if I'm lucky enough to solve this, thx a lot for the information !